# Laravel Querybuilder join on LIKE

Tags: php, laravel

I am attempting to join two tables using the Laravel's query builder however I seem to be having an issue getting the desired result using the query builder, I can however get it quite simply using a raw SQL statement. I simply want to return all mod rows that have the corrosponding value in the `tag` column in the `tags` table.

```
Schema

--------------
mods
--------------
id - int - (primary key)
name - varchar

--------------
tags
--------------
id - int
modid - int - (primary key of its parent mod)
tag - varchar
```

Working SQL query

`SELECT * FROM mod JOIN tags ON tags.tag LIKE '%FPS%'`

Query Builder

```
DB::table('mods')
 ->join('tags', function ($join) {
     $join->on('tags.tag', 'like', '%FPS%');
 })
 ->get();
```

Currently this is telling me: `Unknown column '%FPS%' in 'on clause'` but I am unsure how else to structure this. I intend on adding more `orOn` clauses as well as I will want to get results on multiple tags but firstly I just want to get a single tag working.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: is 'FPS'  constant or a column?

Comment: Sorry 'tag' is the column, FPS is the value. I will post the schema. I hardcoded that FPS in there for brevity's sake but in practice it will be a variable.

Comment: The third parameter of join in laravel needs to be a column of an existing table.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM mod JOIN tags ON tags.tag LIKE '%FPS%'
```

Your query builder is refusing to generate this query because it's nonsense!

To work correctly, a `JOIN` clause needs to compare two columns for equality -- one column on each side of the join table. A `JOIN` clause that doesn't do this is functionally "downgraded" to a `WHERE` clause. In the case of this query, the two tables end up cross joined.

What you probably want is:

```
SELECT * FROM mod
  JOIN tags ON tags.modid = mod.id
  WHERE tags.tag LIKE '%FPS%';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$join->on('tags.tag', 'like', '%FPS%');
```

Try by replacing

```
$join->where('tags.tag', 'like', '%FPS%');
```

Answer (score 1):

This because the `on` method waiting a name of a field not a query value if you want it to deal with it in this way, you should use `DB::raw('%FPS%')`.

Maybe you are trying to do something like the following:

```
DB::table('mods')
    ->select(DB::raw('mods.id as modid, mods.name, tags.id as tagid, tags.tag'))
    ->join('tags', function ($join) {
        $join->on('tags.modid', '=', 'mods.id');
    })
    ->where('tags.tag', 'like', '%FPS%')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to see what is run in the database use 
dd(DB::getQueryLog()) 
to see what queries were run.

Try this
Thank you

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer